# After each startup after a few minute laptop(ubuntu 20.4) get's so slow

Tags: 20.04, cpu, fan

For the last 20days, my laptop has become so slow. I use ubuntu 20.4 lts. My pc has a dual boot with windows 10. I switched to ubuntu but when I start ubuntu fan runs at high speed it does not happen when I open windows. this was from the beginning of ubuntu dual boot. But I could survive with that but now it has become so slow fan also runs faster very few apps makes it tremendously slow which was not the case before. also, I have 8cpu(4 core) but a few apps make it 100% occupied. I don't know what to do.

1. Tried some commands to reduce fan noise (does not work)
2. cannot find why my cpu is always busy. (tried top but not so helpful)

What I want is, my pc does not get slow without any reason. 
I provided 3 image to show the statistics.

**NOTE: weather cpu uses is 100% or very less laptop works slow**

**CPU statistics:**

[image]

**Running processes:**

[image]

**GPU INFO:**

[image]

**Gnome Info added**
[image]

Comment: @Abur  welcome to AskUbuntu! can you post some info about the GPU?  like;  nvidia-smi  if you have nvidia;  or something else?

Comment: Sir, I have provided my GPU info

Comment: You have the wrong version of CUDA installed. You have 10.2, and you should be running with 11.6.

Comment: I use pytorch, in pytorch official website pytorch.org cuda cuda version are prefered 10.2 and 11.3. That's why i installed 10.2 @heynnema

Comment: @AbdurRahimSheikh Then you'll need to use an older version of Nvidia driver software. Notice in `nvidia-smi` in the top-right corner it tells you what version of CUDA you should be running (not that it's actually running).

Comment: @AbdurRahimSheikh Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema sir I have added my gnome info.

Comment: sir, I have seen that it requires 11.6 so I am going to make them for the same cuda, then I'll notify you.

Comment: You have `user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` twice, so remove one. I'm not a fan of the gcampax.github.com extensions, so disable/remove the ones that you really don't use.

Comment: Alhamdulillah, I have reset my gnome-shell and installed cuda-toolkit for 11.3 it looks like the problem has minimized. I'll give you another feedback after 1week. 
thank you very much sir @heynnema

Comment: @AbdurRahimSheikh CUDA 11.6 is available at https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

With the version of Nvidia video driver that you have installed, you need to run CUDA 11.6, not 10.2 or 11.3. Version 11.6 can be downloaded [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local).

You also have a problem with high gnome-shell CPU usage, and with your gnome-shell extensions. You have installed user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com twice, so remove one. I'm not a fan of the gcampax.github.com extensions, so disable/remove the ones that you really don't use.

Comment: Sir you solved my problem, it was the reason. But what i did is,
1) changed the nvidia driver to 11.3
2) and reset to default extension.

Comment: @AbdurRahimSheikh Why didn't you install the CUDA 11.6 that I gave the link for?

Comment: sir i did not go for cuda 11.6 because of pytorch. But 11.3 is also working fine. Thank you again.